# Reducing the amount of database queries on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm working on an application that has to parse a large XML file and use the data inside of it to create entities in the database. The code for creating the entities is the following part of the a controller call:

```
def create
    parser = EuroPassVacancy.new params[:vacancy][:file].tempfile.path
    ids = parser.collect_vacancy_ids
    ids.each do |vacancy_id|
      country = Country.find_or_create_by_code(:code => parser.country_code(vacancy_id), :name => parser.country_code(vacancy_id))
      company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(:name => parser.employer_name(vacancy_id), :address => parser.employer_address(vacancy_id),
                                                  :contact => parser.employer_contact(vacancy_id), :phone => parser.employer_phone(vacancy_id),
                                                  :email => parser.employer_email(vacancy_id), :fax => parser.employer_fax(vacancy_id),
                                                  :country => country)
      Vacancy.create(:pes_id => parser.pes_id(vacancy_id), :title => parser.title(vacancy_id), :description => parser.description(vacancy_id),
                     :country => country, :region_code => parser.region_code(vacancy_id), :company_id => company, :isco_code => parser.isco_code(vacancy_id),
                     :nace_code => parser.nace_code(vacancy_id))
    end
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end
```

It's a pretty heavy loop, but i'm reasonably confident that the parsing is going ok. What currently bothers me is the amount of queries beeing generated for each create statement. Below is a small copy of 2 insert statement of Vacancies:

```
AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `vacancies` (`country_id`, `pes_id`, `title`, `region_code`, `isco_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `description`, `company_id`, `nace_code`) VALUES (9, 50, 'KonstruktÃ©r strojnÃ­, StrojÃ­renÅ¡tÃ­ technici projektanti, konstruktÃ©Å™i', 'RL041', 3118, '2011-05-25 13:19:16', '2011-05-25 13:19:16', 'ÃšSO - strojnÃ­. Konstrukce nÃ¡strojÅ¯ na tvÃ¡Å™enÃ­ a lisovÃ¡nÃ­ kovÅ¯, forem na lisovÃ¡nÃ­ plastÅ¯. Znalost tech. a prÃ¡vnÃ­ch norem, ISO 9001, 14001 souvisejÃ­cÃ­ch s vÃ½robnÃ­m programem v rozsahu potÅ™ebnÃ©m pro vÃ½voj produktu a konstrukci vÃ½robnÃ­ch prostÅ™edkÅ¯ - lisovÃ¡nÃ­ a tvÃ¡Å™enÃ­ kovÅ¯, plastÅ¯, montÃ¡Å¾nÃ­ch pÅ™Ã­pravkÅ¯, PC - konstrukÄ�nÃ­ SW - CAD, 3-D (Solid Edge vÃ½hodou), OFFICE Outlook, NJ/AJ uÅ¾ivatelskÃ¡ ÃºroveÅˆ, Å˜P sk. B.', 1, 0)
  SQL (31.2ms)  COMMIT
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `countries` (`updated_at`, `name`, `code`, `created_at`) VALUES ('2011-05-25 13:19:18', 'cy', 'cy', '2011-05-25 13:19:18')
  SQL (63.0ms)  COMMIT
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'ÎšÎ›Î•Î™Î¤ÎŸÎ£ Î“Î•Î©Î¡Î“Î™ÎŸÎ¥ & Î¥Î™ÎŸÎ£ Î›Î™ÎœÎ™Î¤Î•Î”' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'ÎšÎ›Î•Î™Î¤ÎŸÎ£ Î“Î•Î©Î¡Î“Î™ÎŸÎ¥ & Î¥Î™ÎŸÎ£ Î›Î™ÎœÎ™Î¤Î•Î”' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'ÎšÎ›Î•Î™Î¤ÎŸÎ£ Î“Î•Î©Î¡Î“Î™ÎŸÎ¥ & Î¥Î™ÎŸÎ£ Î›Î™ÎœÎ™Î¤Î•Î”') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'Î Î‘Î�Î™ÎšÎšÎŸÎ£ Î Î™Î£Î£ÎŸÎ¥Î¡Î™ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎ‘Î™ Î‘Î”Î•Î›Î¦ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎŸ Î›Î¤Î”' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (15.6ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'Î Î‘Î�Î™ÎšÎšÎŸÎ£ Î Î™Î£Î£ÎŸÎ¥Î¡Î™ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎ‘Î™ Î‘Î”Î•Î›Î¦ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎŸ Î›Î¤Î”' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'Î Î‘Î�Î™ÎšÎšÎŸÎ£ Î Î™Î£Î£ÎŸÎ¥Î¡Î™ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎ‘Î™ Î‘Î”Î•Î›Î¦ÎŸÎ£ ÎšÎŸ Î›Î¤Î”') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'THE DELHI PALACE INDIAN RESTAURANT LTD' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'THE DELHI PALACE INDIAN RESTAURANT LTD' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'THE DELHI PALACE INDIAN RESTAURANT LTD') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ADVISOR , STELLA PAPADOPOULOU APPIOU' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ADVISOR , STELLA PAPADOPOULOU APPIOU' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'EURES ADVISOR , STELLA PAPADOPOULOU APPIOU') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `companies` (`email`, `phone`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `address`, `contact`, `fax`, `updated_at`, `name`) VALUES ('sappiou@dl.mlsi.gov.cy', '00357 22 403000', 10, '2011-05-25 13:20:13', 'MOUSEIOU STREET 3 1102 , Î›Î•Î¥ÎšÎ©Î£Î™Î‘', 'STELLA PAPADOPOULOU APPIOU', '00357 22 873170/1', '2011-05-25 13:20:13', 'EURES ADVISOR , STELLA PAPADOPOULOU APPIOU')
  SQL (31.2ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ASSISTANT , NORA LANDA' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ASSISTANT , NORA LANDA' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'EURES ASSISTANT , NORA LANDA') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `companies` (`email`, `phone`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `address`, `contact`, `fax`, `updated_at`, `name`) VALUES ('nlanda@dl.mlsi.gov.cy', '00357 25 827327', 10, '2011-05-25 13:20:29', '67 FRANKLIN ROOSEVELT AV 3011 , Î›Î•ÎœÎ•Î£ÎŸÎ£', 'NOT AVAILABLE', '00357 25 306563', '2011-05-25 13:20:29', 'EURES ASSISTANT , NORA LANDA')
  SQL (31.2ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'Î•Î›Î•Î�Î‘ Î¤Î–Î™ÎŸÎ’Î‘Î�Î—' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'Î•Î›Î•Î�Î‘ Î¤Î–Î™ÎŸÎ’Î‘Î�Î—' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'Î•Î›Î•Î�Î‘ Î¤Î–Î™ÎŸÎ’Î‘Î�Î—') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `companies` (`email`, `phone`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `address`, `contact`, `fax`, `updated_at`, `name`) VALUES ('georgiam85@hotmail.com', '0035723833780', 10, '2011-05-25 13:20:45', 'Î”Î‘Î¦Î�Î—Î£ 11-13 5314 AMMOHOSTOS', 'MRS GEORGIA MASIA', '0035723833177', '2011-05-25 13:20:45', 'Î•Î›Î•Î�Î‘ Î¤Î–Î™ÎŸÎ’Î‘Î�Î—')
  SQL (31.2ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'cy' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ADVISOR , MINAS HADJICONSTANTI' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'EURES ADVISOR , MINAS HADJICONSTANTI' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 10 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'EURES ADVISOR , MINAS HADJICONSTANTI') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `companies` (`email`, `phone`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `address`, `contact`, `fax`, `updated_at`, `name`) VALUES ('mhadjiconstanti@dl.mlsi.gov.cy', '00357 24 805328', 10, '2011-05-25 13:21:01', 'P.O.BOX 40136 6301 , Î›Î‘Î¡Î�Î‘ÎšÎ‘', 'MINAS HADJICONSTANTI', '00357 24 304532', '2011-05-25 13:21:01', 'EURES ADVISOR , MINAS HADJICONSTANTI')
  SQL (62.4ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Country Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`code` = 'it' LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'SAILER ANDREAS' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`name` = 'SAILER ANDREAS' AND `companies`.`country_id` = 8 AND (`companies`.`name` = BINARY 'SAILER ANDREAS') LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `companies` (`email`, `phone`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `address`, `contact`, `fax`, `updated_at`, `name`) VALUES ('info@asailer.it', '+39-0471-932632', 8, '2011-05-25 13:21:18', 'A.Duerer-Str. 20 - Via Duerer 20 39100-Bozen - Bolzano', 'Giulia Morello', '+39-0471-932691', '2011-05-25 13:21:18', 'SAILER ANDREAS')
  SQL (30.0ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO `vacancies` (`country_id`, `pes_id`, `title`, `region_code`, `isco_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `description`, `company_id`, `nace_code`) VALUES (8, 64, 'ricerca di ingegnere e architetto per studio di ingegneria', 'R3311', 4190, '2011-05-25 13:21:24', '2011-05-25 13:21:24', 'Studio di ingegneria cerca, anche per subito, un ingegnere e un architetto, per la progettazione architettonica e strutturale, stima e contabilitÃ  di opere, il tutto nel settore delle costruzioni civili e delle opere speciali . E\' richiesta ottima conoscenza di autocad, pacchetto office e programmi di strutture e contabilitÃ . Sede di lavoro: Bolzano centro: si chiede gentilmente che venga inviato un curriculum professionale con foto allegata.', 1, 74)
  SQL (62.4ms)  COMMIT
```

There seems to be ALOT more select queries for the countries & companies going on than I'd like to have. I was wondering if an optimalization can be done about the code to reduce these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to crack this is to cache the lookups or creations you perform. For instance, you're selecting the same country over and over again which is, as you've identified, wasteful.

You can do this by defining a helper method:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.resolve_country(options)
    @resolved_countries ||= { }

    @resolved_countries[options[:code]] ||= Country.find_or_create_by_code(options)
  end
end
```

This will load your country only once and if this pattern is applied to other models it should significantly speed up your loading.

One thing to keep in mind is when you may need to reset these caches for testing purposes. Adding a method to do this is always a good idea, and isn't hard:

```
def self.reset_cache!
  @resolved_countries = nil
end
```

This can be put in your `setup` method for your model's unit tests.

Comment: wow interesting material. I'll definitly take a look at this and see if it makes it faster. Is there any detailed information about this somewhere? I mean caching in RoR ?

Comment: There's a method called `memoize` that's added by Rails that allows you to write helper methods like this, though the internals aren't much more sophisticated than what you see here. Be careful when caching to throw out unwanted content. For instance you may want to reset the cache after you've finished inserting to release any memory occupied by those cached instances.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm also gonne look into memcached to see if this can bring soem help